# Why I am getting an error when I use webview in android?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am new to android and have written the code for web view to display the url given onto that.

The error is as below

> [image]

Why I am getting this error I have used the correct logic in my problems and i haven't got any errors

So kindly please let me know how to rectify it ?

Th code used is :

```
package com.coded.sandeep;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

can anyone debug or it is an internet connection error ?

Comment: Have you given Internet Permissions in your manifest ?

Comment: how to give permission in manifest no i havent touched the manifest file @Kedarnath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a androidmanifest.xml file in your project. Just open that file and write following line init.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

You need to write this line after <uses-sdk tag and before <application> tag.
```

See the image below,

> [image]

Comment: +1 for posted late but based on op requiremnt posted.

Comment: @Kedarnath also +1 up for your answer.

Comment: @Sandeep, You welcome, Keep in touch for any android related help :)

Comment: @Sandeep Yes tell me please. But why you un-accept my answer ? It seems you are new to accept an answer. Just for your information. At a time you can accept only one best answer. not all answer.

Comment: wait let me check @Kedarnath

Comment: @Sandeep, You did accept it, but when you select Pankaj's answer, it automatically un-accept mine answer. Remember that, at a time you can select only one best answer, suitable to your query.

Comment: Ya i am new guy bro sorry yaar @Kedarnath

Comment: @Sandeep, Its ok, Now tell me your problem.

Comment: @Kedarnath i am building an app and i want to use animation to a button when i click that button it has to become big how should i do that

Comment: how to do it any code or any help i will get @Kedarnath

Comment: @Sandeep, How big button you want ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49944/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-sandeep)

Comment: i have 9 buttons and when i click on any button it has to become big and populate it data required data in the sense like other XML file etc @Kedarnath

Comment: big in the sense till that scroll view @Kedarnath

Answer (score 2):

add below permission into your `manifest.xml` file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and also make sure your `Internet Data Connection Turn ON`

Answer (score 1):

Add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file.

```
You have to add this line:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml
```